# dictionary of dictionaries, find keys in common for values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, lookup

I have a big dictionary of dictionaries with a lot of elements like this:

```
'470046757': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_04:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate4', 'Board': 'easyBoard10', 'Branch': 'branchController04', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_9', 'Channel': 'channel002\n'}
```

and the next element is

```
'3646457': {'Cmstrk':'cms_trk_dcs_13:CAEN',...,'Channel':'channel005\n'}
```

and so on.

The `key1` is `'2383495'` and the `key2` (or value for first dictionary) `Cmstrk`, `Crate`, ..., `Channel`, etc. with the respective values which might the same for different `key1` (all `key1` are different between them)

How can I know the `key1` in common that two or more values can have, I mean
if I type `branchController04,CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_9` I need all `key1` with that property.

I already did a script that returns the `key1` for certain value of `key2` (I type for example `channel002\n` and returns `'54654556'`) but I do not know about keys in common.

Comment: If you have some problems with indexing and iterating over structure, it's a case to create your own.

Comment: i have a dictionary(key1) of dictionaries(key2 with its respective values) and i want to know the keys (key1) in common for a given value (values of key2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't know in which `key2` you're looking for.

```
keyword = 'branchController04'
matchingKey2 = None
foundKey1s = []
for k1 in myDict:
    if not matchingKey2 :
        for k2 in myDict[k1]:
            if myDict[k1][k2]==keyword:
                matchingKey2 = k2
                foundKey1s.append(k1)
    else:
        if myDict[k1][matchingKey2]==keyword:
            foundKey1s.append(k1)
```

EDIT: After re-reading your question, I understand it could be any `key2`. If so:

```
keyword = 'branchController04'
foundKey1s = {k1 for k2 in myDict[k1] for k1 in myDict if myDict[k1][k2]==keyword}
```

I use a set in case multiple `k2` values match `keyword` in one sub-dict

Comment: the thing is i have a lot of elements like the one in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
def db_position(db, search_name):
    # Iterating over main dict
    for main_key, main_value in zip(db.keys(), db.values()):
        # over secondary dict(s)
        for secn_key, secn_value in zip(main_value.keys(), main_value.values()):
            if secn_value == search_name:
                print("Main: ", main_key)
                print("Secn: ", secn_key)

database = dict()
database.update({'470046757': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_04:CAEN',
                               'Crate': 'easyCrate4',
                               'Board': 'easyBoard10',
                               'Branch': 'branchController04',
                               'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_9',
                               'Channel': 'channel002\n'}})
database.update({'3646457': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_13:CAEN',
                             'Channel': 'channel005\n'}})

db_position(database, 'easyCrate4')
```

Run:

```
>python dicts.py
('Main: ', '470046757')
('Secn: ', 'Crate')
```